# Get HTTP Response before Async call in gwt

Tags: javascript, java, http, gwt

I want to get the **Http Response** of URL in gwt before the Async method calls.

Below is my working code but i want to execute it before the Async call.

```
  RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "http://localhost:8080");
    try {
        builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException ex) {

    }
    return response.getStatusCode();
```

Also note that i am using **JavaScript** in my project. Is there any way to write this code in **javaScript** and retrieve the **response** in my **OnModuleLoad** method?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use javascript/jquery promise.

Javascript promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Jquery promise:
https://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: But even if you access (get) the getStatusCode value before the RequestCallback (asyc) is called, the value will be irrelevant, probably the default value of the primitive type. You should wait until the actual response is received or failed, and as javascript is mono-thread, you cannot block to wait, you can only wait using callbacks. But, as @MaheshGosemath said, you can use an async wrappers as [Promise](https://github.com/gwtquery/gwtquery) or [Observable](https://github.com/intendia-oss/rxjava-gwt).

Comment: I was calling the api from client side. But i have to validate it into server side. So i made the servlet and validate it from javascript. Solved :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the simple function in javascript with **async : false**. Then i  hit the url and get the response.

This response will be taken in onModuleLoad using native method. Sync calling.

Solved :-)